# How to access a class object inside a list when a value for one of the class attributes is given in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, object, attributes

I have a list of class objects and I want to know how can I print a particular class object inside the list given a value for one of its attributes.

Here is my code:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

lst = [Person("A",1), Person("B",2), Person("C", 3)]

inputAge = int(input("Age: "))

if inputAge == 2:
  print() #this should print the class object with age 2 from the list
```

I don't know what should I put inside the `print()` code.

Comment: You cannot print the required object directly. You would need to loop over your list, find the person whose age equals 2 and then print that object.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can find the first element of the list having a specific attribute (precondition: all objects of the list have that attribute):

```
obj = next((x for x in lst if x.age == inputAge), None)
```

`obj` is `None` if such an object can't be found in the list.

Once you found the object, you can do whatever you want with it, including printing (`print(obj)`).

If you want the printing of the object to be meaningful you would have to do something like this:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  def __str__(self):
    return 'name: ' + self.name + ' age: ' + self.age
```

This is the complete example:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  def __str__(self):
    return 'name: ' + self.name + ' age: ' + self.age

lst = [Person("A",1), Person("B",2), Person("C", 3)]

inputAge = int(input("Age: "))
obj = next((x for x in lst if x.age == inputAge), None)
print(obj) # prints the object with age = inputAge
```

Comment: so the print function would be `print(obj)` ?

Comment: @chilliyayi Yes, but it's not going to print anything useful to you... If you want the print function to be more useful than you should add a `__str__(self)` method to your class. This method should return a string, which represents exactly what is printed